# PHP preg_replace field before bringing through from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a column within my MySQL database which stores a product description that includes non-alphanumeric characters. I'm trying to run a PHP dump of various fields within the datebase using my Apache Server - and I would like to remove all of the non-alphanumeric characters from the product description before being returned.

```
// load all stock
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

?>



<? 

$size = '3';
// check if size is available 
if($line['quantity_size_'.$size.''] > 0 ) { 
?>

<?=$line['product_id']?>, 
<?=$line['code_size_'.$size.'']?>,
EAN, 
<?=$line['title']?>, 
<?=$_GET['brand']?>, 
<?=$_GET['brand']?>,
**<?=$line preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', '', ['amazon_desc']),**
<?=$size?>,
<?=$line['colour']?>, 

....
```

I've emboldened the relevant line above - this seems to return a T_String error.

Any body help?

Thanks

A

Comment: YOu're missing the array name before `['amazon_desc']`.

Comment: i think it should like this  `preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', '', $line['amazon_desc'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?=$line preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', '', ['amazon_desc']),
```

should be:

```
<?=preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', '', $line['amazon_desc']) ?>
```

This basic function calling syntax, I don't know where you got the idea that you could be the array name before the function, and the index inside the arguments.